# Ruby: NoMethodError, but why?

Tags: ruby, nomethoderror

I was working on a simple Pi Generator while learning Ruby, but I kept getting NoMethodError on RubyMine 6.3.3, so I decided to make a new project and new class with as simple as possible, and I **STILL** get NoMethodError. Any reason?

```
class Methods
  def hello (player)
    print "Hello, " << player
  end
  hello ("Annie")
end
```

And the error I get is:

```
C:/Users/Annie the Eagle/Documents/Coding/Ruby/Learning Environment/methods.rb:5:in `<class:Methods>': undefined method `hello' for Methods:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: you're calling the method inside the class definition. I'm unsure its intended.

Comment: I'm not sure of your background / level of experience in OO programming, so just to check: do you understand the difference between classes and instances (and class methods and instance methods)? The answer assumes you do...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have defined an *instance method* and are trying to call it as a *method of a class*. Thus you need to make the method `hello` a class method, not an instance method of the class `Methods`.

```
class Methods
  def self.hello(player)
    print "Hello, " << player
  end
  hello("Annie")
end
```

Or, if you want to define it as *instance method* then call it as below :

```
class Methods
  def hello(player)
    print "Hello, " << player
  end
end
Methods.new.hello("Annie")
```

Comment: Oh wow... so self.hello would be the same as the C# equivalent of "static (return type) hello"?

When would it be right to use just "def hello"

Comment: You should remove the space between method name and parenthesis.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to call an instance method as a class method.

Here's some code that illustrates the difference between the two in ruby:

```
class Person

  # This is a class method - note it's prefixed by self
  # (which in this context refers to the Person class)
  def self.species
    puts 'Human'
    # Note: species is OK as a class method because it's the same 
    # for all instances of the person class - ie, 'Bob', 'Mary', 
    # 'Peggy-Sue', and whoever else, are ALL Human.
  end

  # The methods below aren't prefixed with self., and are
  # therefore instance methods

  # This is the construct, called automatically when
  # a new object is created
  def initialize(name)
    # @name is an instance variable
    @name = name
  end

  def say_hello
    puts "Hello from #{@name}"
  end

end
```

And now try it out, calling the methods...

```
# Call a class method...
# We're not referring to any one 'instance' of Person,
Person.species #=> 'Human'

# Create an instance
bob = Person.new('Bob')

# Call a method on the 'Bob' instance
bob.say_hello #=> 'Hello from Bob'

# Call a method on the Person class, going through the bob instance
bob.class.species #=> 'Human'

# Try to call the class method directly on the instance
bob.species #=> NoMethodError

# Try to call the instance method on the class
# (this is the error you are getting)
Person.say_hello #=> NoMethodError
```

Answer (score 1):

You've created an instance method, but you're calling a class method. In order to call `hello("Annie")`, you have to make an instance of Methods. For instance:

```
class Methods
  def self.hello(player)
      print "Hello, " << player
  end
end

my_method = Methods.new
my_method.hello("Annie")
```

This would output `Hello, Annie`

Answer (score 0):

By defining a method with **def method_name args** you are defining a instance method that will be included in every object of that class, but not in the class itself.

On the other hand, by **def self.method_name args** you will get a class method that will be directly in the class, without the need of instanciate an object from it.

So If you have this:

```
Class Test
   def self.bar
   end

   def foo
   end

end
```

You can execute the instance method this way:

```
a = Test.new
a.foo
```

And as for the class one should be:

```
Test.foo
```